# After return redirect to a page the variable doesnot show on view page

Tags: laravel-5.3

In controller i have this code. When i want to show company variable on view it gives the error.
This is my controller.

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $validation = array(
    'email' =>'required',
    'password' => 'required');
    //dd($email);
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validation);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        return redirect('login_with_assismo')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        $admin = DB::table('admin')
                    ->where('email',$email)
                    ->where('password', $password)
                    ->where('is_admin', 1)
                    ->first();
        if (!empty($admin)) {
             $company = DB::table('company_details')
                           ->where('id', $admin->company_id)
                           ->pluck('company_name');
             if (!empty($company)) {
                  return redirect('company_details')->with('company', $company);                  
              } 

           }   
        }
}
```

and this is my view

```
<input type="text" name="company_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company name" value = "{{ company }}">
```

This is the error when i execute this code:
 Use of undefined constant company_name - assumed 'company_name' (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/assismo/resources/views/company_details.blade.php)

Comment: You will need to add way more code so we can understand this. We dont even see where you use "company_name" since you output $company in your value of the input. It seems like either some code is missing or you changed someting wrong in this snippet.

Comment: i actually refered to the view, but let me check. Please clarify why you bind $company as value to an  input. You bind an object to a string - update: sorry i just saw that you pluck the name as variable

Comment: Well as the error states the problem is cleary within your VIEW. You will need to find the part of the view that throws the error. Most probably you used company_name instead of $company_name or you used $company_name instead of $company

Comment: is there anything wrong with this code. I just want to return company variable to my view in input value with return redirect only not with return view().

Comment: Please read my comment. Not your controller is the problem, but your view

Comment: $company is variable and company_name is the column of the table so i dont think that this is the issue. if i use $ it gives the error undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

The undefined constant error means that you probably tried something like

```
<div><!-- or other html -->
  {{ company_name}}
</div><!-- ... -->
```

Even though it should be

```
<div><!-- or other html -->
  {{ $company_name}}
</div><!-- ... -->
```

Howveer, it does not seem you return a company name variable at all so probably it should be

```
<div><!-- or other html -->
  {{ $company }}
</div><!-- ... -->
```

Additional remarks:

Your code is highly insecure. You should never ever use this in a productive enviroment. You dont crypt the password or anything. It actually seems like your passwords are stored plain.

You should also consider to write your own requests (php artisan:make request) and move validation somewhere else.

I also don't see a reason to use DB Facade here instead of the actual Object you are interested in.

Comment: Its not working at all still. and this is for testing so i not crypt of password

Comment: well you still did not add your view details. I claimed 3 times we need it to give a more specific answer

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <label for="companyname">Company Name</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="company_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company name" value = "{{ $company }}">
                               </div>

Comment: Either you post WAY MORE details about your view or you will need to find it on your own. PLEASE i told you that it is not THIS part. You will have the problem somewhere else where you try to access the variable company_name WHICH DOES NOT EXIST.

Comment: The only place where i am trying to acces company_name variable is this input type value  nowhere else. when i keep empty this value the page show perfectly.